# Why is a cucumber scenario failing only after I run the full test suite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, testing, cucumber

If I run the specific scenario, it's all green.
If I only run the cucumber suite (aka. rake cucumber), it's all green.
However, if I run the full test suite, (aka. rake), a single scenario fails.

I assume this has something to do with the state of the database and my configuration. I wrote the cucumber scenarios to assume an initially empty database, and I'm building small datasets for the individual scenarios.

I'm using DatabaseCleaner, with the truncation strategy, and my understanding is that this will wipe the db clean. Am I mistaken? Is there data lingering that might have been created when the unit and functional tests ran? Is there a quick way to ensure that cucumber starts clean?

Happy to start posting code and wading into config specifics...

thanks

Comment: It's quitte hard to answer this without getting into specifics as there a lot possibilities that can cause this.
Are you stubbing anything? Altering any constants? are you using Timecop? Setting any state on a configuration/global object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Head in hands. Deep shame.

I was never actually cleaning the database.

I was setting the strategy but never pulling the trigger.

features/support/env.rb

Before:

```
begin
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
rescue NameError
  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
end
```

After:

```
begin
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
rescue NameError
  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
end
```

Don't let it happen to you.

Sigh.